# Google Scholar: how to search for a close title match

Tags: google-scholar

I am trying to search Google Scholar for articles based on title, but where I may have only an approximate title. Usually what I have is very close, but may vary slightly in punctuation (hyphenation or not, different unicode representation of apostrophe, etc.) or may have or be missing a few extra words at the start or end of the title.

When I use `intitle:"Sample Title Goes Here"` it will only match exact matches.  I think when I do `intitle:Sample Title Goes Here` the `intitle` qualifier only applies to the first word.  When I try `intitle:Sample intitle:Title intitle:Goes intitle:Here` it only matches if all these words are in the title (so if I have a spurious word in my search string, it fails. (I've also noted some very strange behavior if I put a space between `intitle:` and my query.)

What is the best way to do what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 2):

you could:

- use the Google scholar [Advanced Search](https://scholar.google.com/schhp?hl=en#d=gs_asd&t=1698798746305), with all your keywords in the “with at least one of the words” field, and selecting “in the title of the article”;
- use `intitle:` in the normal search, combined with `OR` in between each of your keywords (for example: `intitle:brain OR intelligence OR memory`)

If you're not sure of the spelling of one of the keywords, I suggest writing all the possible spellings you can think of.

For more information on google scholar advanced search: https://library.acg.edu/how-to-guides/google-scholar/advanced-searching (it confirms that there shouldn't be a space between `intitle:` and your first keyword.

Comment: does OR prefer matches with as many hits as possible?  It didn't seem to in my tests.  And would I need intitle: before each of the OR terms?

Comment: 1. I'm not sure about the number of matches, but you can sort either by relevance or date in the left panel. 2. It doesn't seem that you need intitle: before each term; just once at the start as in my example above.